# Are the new Epic and Legendary badges for consective days, or total days?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

The new Epic and Legendary badges are:

- Epic: Hit the daily reputation cap for 50 days
- Legendary: Hit the daily reputation cap for 150 days

Are these for any days, or must they be consecutive days?

Comment: Good question.  I think the "for X days" rather than "on X days" implies continuous time, meaning consecutive, but it could be made clearer if that's so or disambiguated if it's not.

Comment: i'd assume "overall" rather than "consecutive" from the current wording, contrary to Adam's opinion, but i agree it could clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any days.

This indicates to me that the Fanatic and Enthusiast (nee Woot) badges should have the word "consecutive" in their description..

EDIT: updated the descriptions to be more clear.

Comment: Oh good, so I should be able to get a Legendary at some point. On the other hand, the consecutive requirement of Fanatic makes it hard especially when one likes to take holidays away from the Internet Points Game.

Comment: @Greg: What's a holiday?

Comment: Out of your mobile internet coverage area.

Comment: I have AT&T -- that's 80% of the US!

Comment: That reminds me of the guy that went camping.... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13049/let-people-still-earn-the-woot-badge-if-they-register-for-a-holiday

Comment: I can log in on my phone, but it's pretty awkward.  Fortunately, my mobility is limited by a geriatric cat, so I can probably get Fanatic on my home broadband.