# When are the reputation cap badges assigned?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

When are these "Hit the daily reputation cap on X days" badges assigned? Are they assigned when somebody's reputation always grown in X days, or something else?

Comment: The days don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: I'm not sure whether http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52785/indicating-that-users-are-helpful-not-just-the-answer or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/are-the-new-epic-and-legendary-badges-for-consective-days-or-total-days answers your question. Or if the concept of the badge itself is confusing you, check out the original request here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/award-badge-for-hitting-daily-rep-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are awarded when your daily reputation exceeds 200 points on 50/150 days.  If you visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll all the way to the bottom, you'll see the last two lines look like this:

```
rep cap was reached on x days
rep cap was exceeded on y days
```

I remember reading an answer from Jeff saying the second number applies to those badges.

Comment: Yes, it is the second number that applies. Check out the comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it/49405#49405) for the official statement.

Comment: @Grace: indeed, and [this answer from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49147/possible-bug-in-legendary-badge-calculation/49235#49235) explains it too.